# How can i use responsiveslides.js with jimdo?

Tags: javascript, head, responsive-slides

i would like to use [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com/) with jimdo;

how should i modify the header of my jimdo-page that it will work?

Answer (score 1):

First link files:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
```

Then add markup

```
<ul class="rslides">
<li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="3.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

And then you can modify css accordingly.